# Excel VBA: Repeat IF statement on string range to retrospective rows

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, row, vba

I'm struggling to find the answers I need on this, hoping someone can help. I get the feeling the code I've written will need to be approached differently to achieve what I want to achieve.

I have produced some code that produces an IF statement on a cell and displays a corresponding description in another cell next to it, I have also added code to ensure it automatically updates if this value is changed. This works.

I now need to extend the code so it loops down the cells and repeats the same function. checking the IF statement and displaying the corresponding description in the respective cell next to it.

Sheet VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:A10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  On Error GoTo Finalise
  Call Material_String
  Finalize:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Sub Material_String()
  Dim MaterialOption As String
  Dim MaterialDetail As String
  MaterialOption = Range("A2").Value
  If MaterialOption = "a" Then MaterialDetail = "a is bloody good"
  If MaterialOption = "b" Then MaterialDetail = "b is excellent"
  If MaterialOption = "c" Then MaterialDetail = "c is most good"
  If MaterialOption = "d" Then MaterialDetail = "d is simply the best"
  If MaterialOption = "e" Then MaterialDetail = "e's are just amazing"
  Range("C2").Value = MaterialDetail
End Sub
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out [how to loop through a range](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-defined-range.html). Also [Select Case](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/select-case.html) may be helpful too instead of `If` statements.

Comment: If your code is activated by changing a cell, why do you need it to loop through the whole range if most of its cells have not been changed? I'd have thought you have it right as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to loop through all the rows.  You probably just want to work on whichever cell was changed.

You can do this by changing your "work" subroutine (i.e. `Material_String`) to accept a cell as a parameter, and change your `Worksheet_Change` event to pass the cell that has changed.

Sheet VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:A10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  On Error GoTo Finalise
  Dim c As Range
  'Loop through each changed cell, just in case there is more than one
  For Each c In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:A10")).Cells
      Call Material_String(c)
  Next
  Finalize:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Sub Material_String(c As Range)
  Dim MaterialOption As String
  Dim MaterialDetail As String
  MaterialOption = c.Value
  If MaterialOption = "a" Then MaterialDetail = "a is bloody good"
  If MaterialOption = "b" Then MaterialDetail = "b is excellent"
  If MaterialOption = "c" Then MaterialDetail = "c is most good"
  If MaterialOption = "d" Then MaterialDetail = "d is simply the best"
  If MaterialOption = "e" Then MaterialDetail = "e's are just amazing"
  c.Offset(0, 2).Value = MaterialDetail
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you YowE3K. Does the c mean it is looking at the cell? Presumably (as i seem to be finding) I cant reference C again on another IF Intersect statement to then look at another column and call a different module sub on the same Sheet?

Comment: @MattCass There is nothing special about the variable `c`.  It is defined as a `Range` object (i.e. a reference to a range) and I have used it in the `Change` event to refer individually to each cell that was changed in column A (between row 2 and 10).  There is no reason that you couldn't include another loop in your `Change` event code such as `For Each c In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")).Cells` `Call Another_Sub(c)` `Next`

Comment: Please correct typo in word Finalise to Finalize. As both labels need to have same spelling. I could not make this change as edit less than specified characters not permitted.